# Need to trigger event when object has value in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Hi Initially I have created empty javascript object ,

```
var obj = {}
```

I have push two different values to object from different function I need to trigger any event when object has value, for example if value pushed to object then I need to trigger any event and I saw object.watch() but it is not suitable for me,  I dont know my question is wrong or write anyone suggest me for my problem

Comment: Just build a setter function and do whatever you like. Another approach would be *observables*.

Comment: can you please give anyone example for that

Comment: No, there are thousands of examples. Like this: https://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/12/es5-getters-setters/

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj=new Proxy({},{
  set(obj,prop,value){
    alert("setting "+prop+" to "+value);
  }
});
```

Simply use an ES6 Proxy ( [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy))